# Why am I receiving this error when running my Query in Oracle- "RP": invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that I am running and I want the results to be grouped by yesterday's date. When I run my query, i receive an error that says "RP": Invalid identifier.

**Here is my code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW db1.table1 AS
SELECT (SELECT TO_DATE(current_date - 1)  FROM dual) as rp,
       SUM(NVL(sesions,0)) AS session_income, 
       SUM(NVL(non_sessions,0)) AS session_drop, 
       (SUM(NVL(sesions,0))- SUM(NVL(non_session,0))) as CC,
       SUM(NVL(trasnfer,0)) AS Transfer
FROM db1.table1_target
where T_DATE >= (select trunc(sysdate, 'MM') FROM dual) AND
T_DATE <= (SELECT TO_DATE(current_date - 1)  FROM dual) 
GROUP BY rp;
```

Any idea as to why when I run my above query in oracle I receiving an error of:

```
"RP": Invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: 1) The GROUP BY is evaluated before the column alias rp is created.

Comment: 2) Why the subqueries?

Comment: By the way, `create view` isn't a query.

Comment: Why mix `sysdate` and `current_date`? Why is `to_date()` applied to `current_date - 1` when it's already a date?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using subqueries for simple date operations.  You can include "constants" in an aggregation query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(current_date - 1) as rp,
       SUM(NVL(sesions,0)) AS session_income, 
       SUM(NVL(non_sessions,0)) AS session_drop, 
       (SUM(NVL(sesions,0))- SUM(NVL(non_session,0))) as CC,
       SUM(NVL(trasnfer,0)) AS Transfer
FROM db1.table1_target
WHERE T_DATE >= trunc(sysdate, 'MM') AND
      T_DATE <= TO_DATE(current_date - 1)
```